# Dynamic size of container - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, containers, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and came across an issue with `Container` widget's size that has `Row` and `Column` as it's child. I'm aiming to render a `Column` and `Row` widget with dynamic data. The code is as below.

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
  color: Colors.orange.shade400,
 ),
 child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 25.0),
  child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
    Text("PEAK/THURSDAY"),
    Text("\$24,355"),
    weeklyExpenseBuilder(), // Row with Text widgets
   ],
  ),
 ),
)
```

Not fixing the size of the container allows it to take up all the screen space but fixing it's height leads to `RenderFlex overflow` error. Is there any way to let the `Container` widget take only as much space as it's children take.
The design that i'm aiming to looks something like this[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **mainAxisSize** property of a Row or Column is max by default.

Try setting `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` on both the row and column and adding some spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You should always make give size related to width and height of the screen to make the app perfectly responsive

for example you can create a variable

```
 double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

and use it for you Container or fontsize for example

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width / 2,
      child: Text('test',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: width * 0.035,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

And for avoiding overflow you can always user Wrap or Expanded(inside a row or column).